# Page height precision in Microsoft Word

Tags: microsoft-word, text-formatting

I have an issue caused due to Word not accepting the level of precision that I need for page height. Specifically, fractions of millimetres such as 12.34mm are rounded to 12.3mm. When printing labels this discrepancy causes label creep.

Is there any way around this? Perhaps Word doesn't let you set these precise measurements, but editing the file manually could work? (I diff'd a simple extracted document where the only difference was me changing the page height but it didn't provide a clear way forward).

Any ideas would be really helpful. I have Word 2016 and I need the functionality within a document template. A third-party system populates this template but I'm able to change whatever I need to within that template. Many thanks!

Comment: Another thing that can help is to create several successive labels, which could be applicable if label creep involves printing multiples of the same label or the label contents are known in advance and fixed. You can do a similar action on a template by defining several rows instead of a single one. Adjust each label/row so rounding is based on the cumulative requirements. A few labels/rows can give you precision to an additional decimal place or more.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately the rounding (and other aspects) in Word makes for a very difficult task making print ready documents where precision is important. There is a good article [here](http://wordribbon.tips.net/T011388_Words_Native_Measurement_Unit.html) about it.

The solution I have used is to use points instead of millimetres, giving a slightly greater control of the accuracy (where 12.34 mm is closer to 35 points).

It's still not perfect, but may give you slightly greater control of the creep if you have no option but to use Word.

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion, definitely seems to be my best bet. The linked article is a great resource. My final option is a macro to print each page individually, thus potentially 'resetting' the printer in between pages..worth a shot :)